# async function in an Azure Function

Tags: javascript, async-await, azure-functions, azure-function-async

I am getting an error with this javascript function definition in Azure. I am defining this within an Azure function for use by the exported function.

```
async function getData() {
    var data = await postRequest();
    return data;
};
```

Below is the error I am getting in the console. Is async await syntax not supported in Azure functions?

If yes, how would I implement an async call (such as a REST call made with node-rest-client).

```
2018-01-05T10:50:55.448 Function started (Id=a4995e6f-141a-46bb-becf-
468f49f7505d)
2018-01-05T10:50:55.565 Exception while executing function: 
Functions.MyFunctionName. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. 
D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyFunctionName\index.js:90
async function getData() {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at eval (eval at compileFunc (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11388\bin\edge\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:1:80).
2018-01-05T10:50:55.673 Function completed (Failure, Id=a4995e6f-141a-46bb-becf-468f49f7505d, Duration=221ms)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For javascript async syntax support you need to install the latest version of the cli along side with node [v8.x](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/326)

> npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core

Additionally you'll need to [enable the beta runtime on azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#target-the-version-20-runtime) so it also works when deploying.

Comment: I've found that enabling the beta runtime in the Azure portal was not possible after I'd already deployed. I had to create a new function app and enable beta runtime first.